# Android's AsyncTask: multiple params, returning values, waiting

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have been looking at how to implement Android's AsyncTask class for some time now. Basically, I want it to do the classic scenario: simply animate an indefinite loading wheel while I make a network call. However, in practice I'm having some issues getting this to work the way I want.

I have code that looks like this **currently**: (before my desired AsyncTask implementation)

```
 String result = timeConsumingNetworkCall(String someData, ArrayList stuff1);
 doStuff(result);

 String result = timeConsumingNetworkCall(String otherData, ArrayList stuff2);
 doOtherStuff(result);

 String result = timeConsumingNetworkCall(String dataAgain, ArrayList stuff3);
 doYetEvenMore(result);
```

I want to be able to reuse my AsyncTask call to pass data to it, it makes a network call, and then returns me data that I can then process as I wish, like I do above.

Now - this works perfect, except of course the app appears to "hang" with no loading. In comes  AsyncTask. Maybe I just don't quite "get it" yet - but how do I return data OUTSIDE of the AsyncTask so that `doStuffToUI()` etc can use it?

Ultimately, I'd like it if I could use the AsyncTask similar to this:

```
String result = new PostToFile("function_name", keysAndValues).execute().getResult();
doStuff(result); // this shouldn't execute until the AsyncTask is done
```

Am I going about this right? Is this how it should be/can be done? Here's my AsyncTask class below, shortened for brevity.

```
private class PostToFile extends AsyncTask<PostToFile, Void, Void>{
    private String functionName;
    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> postKeyValuePairs;
    private String result = "";

    public PostToFile(String function, ArrayList<NameValuePair> keyValuePairs){
        functionName= function;
        postKeyValuePairs = keyValuePairs;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(BaseActivity.getInstance(), "Loading", "Please wait...", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(PostToFile... params) {                       
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(FUNCTION_KEYWORD, functionName));
        for (int i = 0; i < postKeyValuePairs.size(); i++)            {
            nameValuePairs.add(postKeyValuePairs.get(i));
        }

        try{
            // ***do the POST magic.***
            result = response.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
             // clean up my mess
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String getResult(){
        return result; // can I use this somehow???
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
 }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot in advance. I'm happy to clarify if needed.

Comment: You can write doStuff(result); in onPostExtecute() method

Comment: Well, I'd really rather not do that. Because then I'd have to have multiple AsyncTask objects for every time I'd want to PostToFile, just based on how I receive the data. That sounds messy and too much duplicate code. I just want to put in data, get it out, and parse it.

Comment: @unexpected62 i had same issue if you had solve this pls help me how you had achive this

Answer (score 1):

> doStuff(result); this shouldn't execute until the AsyncTask is done

then you will need to use  [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) which make  Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

because calling of `AsyncTask.get()` freeze main UI thread until  `doInBackground` execution is not complete then u will need to use Thread to avoid freezing of UI and `runOnUiThread` for updating Ui elements after AsyncTask execution complete.

**Example :-**

```
public void  ThreaddoStuff(){

 Thread th=new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
      // start AsyncTask exection here
      String result = new PostToFile("function_name", 
                      keysAndValues).execute().get().getResult();

     // now call doStuff by passing result
     doStuff(result);
    }
  };
th.start();
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of this... there has to be a better way... You're telling me that when I do `new AsynTaskObject(params).execute()` that will start and then the next line is immediately executed before the previous is done? All I want to do is animate the damn loading wheel, not continue running my program! I can't continue unless I have that data which is used to populate the UI for the next screen!! There must be something fundamental I'm missing/not understanding.

Comment: `You're telling me that when I do new AsynTaskObject(params).execute() that will start and then the next line is immediately executed before the previous is done?` -- YES , you get this behavior of AsynTask if you call it without calling get() method and in this case you will need to call `doStuff(result);` inside onPostExecute method because this method called when  doInBackground execution complete. `All I want to do is animate the damn loading wheel` ::--- for this you will need to use  runOnUiThread to update loading wheel from Thread

Answer (score 1):

Make a reusable async task with default onPostExecute implementation and then override default implementation for every call:

```
public static class PostToFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private String functionName;
        private ArrayList<NameValuePair> postKeyValuePairs;
        private String result = "";

        public PostToFile(String function, ArrayList<NameValuePair> keyValuePairs){
            functionName= function;
            postKeyValuePairs = keyValuePairs;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // show progress bar
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // make request and get the result
            return null; // return result
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(String result) {
            super.onCancelled(result);
            // hide progress bar
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // hide progress bar
        }
    }
```

Execute your async task:

```
new PostToFile(function, keyValuePairs) {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result); // this will hide a progress bar

            doStuff(result); 
        }
}.execute();

new PostToFile(otherFunction, otherKeyValuePairs) {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result); // this will hide a progress bar

            doOtherStuff(result); 
        }
}.execute();
```

Comment: I see, and I actually did begin this implementation. However - the issue still remains that when I do new `AsynTaskObject(params).execute()` that will start and then the next line is immediately executed before the `execute()` is necessarily finished. It's not feasible for me to put everything in `onPostExecute()` as it would basically be the rest of my program, lol. I can't move on until I have processed this data, I just want to show a loading wheel while its happening. Perhaps AsyncTask is not actually what I need? Maybe just a ProgressDialog on a new thread?

Comment: Then do all your work (multiple requests and result parsing) in a single doInBackground method. Or move progress bar to activity and start it before executing async tasks, and hide it in onPostExecute of last async task (or better to say, when all tasks will finish)